# Herencia en Python

Tags: python, herencia

Estoy aprendiendo python y estoy practicando la herencia en las clases no puedo lograr hacer que el codigo cuando la clase motoElecrica usa el metodo haciencdoWilly sin haber usado el metodo "arrancar" me muestre un mensaje de que primero se debe arrancar lo que logro es que se imprima en consola que la moto electrica esta "Haciendo willy" incluso cuando no se hace uso del metodo arrancar. Este es mi codigo

```
class Vehiculos():
    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):

        self.marca=marca
        self.modelo=modelo
        self.__enmarcha=False
        self.acelera=False
        self.frena=False

    def arrancar(self, arrancamos):

        self.__enmarcha=arrancamos

        if(self.__enmarcha):
            chequeo=self.__chequeo_interno()

        else:
            return False


        if(self.__enmarcha and chequeo):

            return True and print("El vehiculo está en marcha")


        elif (self.__enmarcha and chequeo==False):

            return False and print("El chequeo no fue exitoso. No se puede arrancar")

        else:

            return False and print("El vehiculo esta parado")


    def __chequeo_interno(self):

        print("Inicializando de chequeo interno")

        self.gasolina="ok"
        self.aceite="ok"

        if (self.gasolina=="ok" and self.aceite=="ok"):

            return True

        else:
            return False


    def acelerando(self, acelerando):

        self.acelera=acelerando

        frenamos=self.frena

        if (self.__enmarcha and self.acelera and frenamos==False):

            return print("El vehiculo está acelerando")

        elif (self.__enmarcha==False and self.acelera and frenamos==False):

            return print("Arrancar el vehiculo primero por favor")

        elif (self.acelera and frenamos):

            return print("No es posible acelerar y frenar al mismo tiempo")


    def frenando(self, frenando):

        self.frena=frenando

        aceleramos=self.acelera

        if(self.__enmarcha and self.frena and aceleramos==False):

            return print("El vehiculo esta frenando")


        elif (self.__enmarcha==False and self.frena and aceleramos==False):

            return print("Arrancar el vehiculo primero por favor")


        elif (self.frena and aceleramos):

            return print("No es posible acelerar y frenar al mismo tiempo")


    def estado(self):

        print("Marca: ", self.marca, "\nModelo: ", self.modelo)


#SUB CLASE

print("-----VEHICULO 1-----")

class moto(Vehiculos):

    def haciendoWilly(self, haciendoWilly):

        andando=self.arrancar


        if(andando and haciendoWilly):

            return print("La moto esta haciendo willy")

        elif(haciendoWilly==False):

            return print("No se esta haciendoWilly")

        elif(andando==False and haciendowilly==True):
            return print("Primero arrancar la moto por favor")



miMoto=moto("Honda", "CBR")

miMoto.estado()

miMoto.arrancar(True)

miMoto.acelerando(True)

miMoto.frenando(False)

miMoto.haciendoWilly(True)

print("------------------------------------------")

#SUB CLASE

print("-----VEHICULO 2-----")

class chata(Vehiculos):

    def carga (self, carga):

        print("El vehiculo soporta una carga máxima de 250 kg")

        carga=int(input("Ingrese el valor en kg de la carga "))

        if(carga>0 and carga<=250):

            return print("El vehiculo esta cargado")

        elif(carga==0):

            return print("El vehiculo NO esta cargado")

        elif(carga<0):

            return print("Por favor ingresar un valor POSITIVO")

        elif(carga>250):

            return print("La carga excede el límite y podría dañar el vehículo")

miChata=chata("Toyota", "Hilux")

miChata.carga(True)

miChata.arrancar(True)

miChata.frenando(True)

print("------------------------------------------")

#SUB CLASE

print("-----VEHICULO 3-----")

class electricos(Vehiculos):

    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):

        self.marca=marca
        self.modelo=modelo
        self.__enmarcha=False
        self.acelera=False
        self.frena=False
        self.autonomia=450
        self.carga=False

    def cargando(self, cargando):

        self.carga=cargando

        if (cargando):

            print("El vehiculo se esta cargando")

        else:

            print("El vehiculo NO se esta cargando")


miElectrico=electricos("Tesla", "Roadster")

miElectrico.cargando(True)

miElectrico.arrancar(True)
print("------------------------------------------")

#SUB CLASE

print("-----VEHICULO 4-----")

class motoElectrica(electricos, moto):

    pass


miMotoE=motoElectrica("Narol", "ATR")

miMotoE.arrancar(False)

miMotoE.haciendoWilly(True)
```

Comment: Usar nombres iguales para una variables y una funcion es una muy pero muy mala practica de programacion: `def haciendoWilly(self, haciendoWilly):`

Comment: Lo voy a tener en cuenta, gracias. Hice los cambios en el codigo pero sigo sin poder hacer que se imprima el mensaje de primero encender el vehículo

Comment: Trata de colocar cosas coherentes, ¿Que significa *La moto esta haciendo willy*?, esa sentencia confunde y no ayuda a depurar.

Comment: En Argentina se le dice "Hacer Willy" cuando una moto levanta la rueda delantera y se mantiene en equilibrio con la trasera, queria que la moto eléctrica herede eso de la moto (vehÍculo 1)

Comment: Te recomiendo señalar que es lo que obtienes y que es lo que deseas obtener. Ademas de describir lo que hereda de cada clase, se mas detallado en tu descripcion.

Comment: ahí edité la pregunta

Comment: El codigo esta mal en esta linea: `andando=self.arrancar`

Comment: arrancar es una funcion, no es una variable asi que solo existe cuando es ejecutado, si solo lo invocas sin los `()`, estas obteniendo el puntero de la funcion, yo pienso que estas pensando que este retorna el estado de la funcion que invocaste inicialmente con `miMotoE.arrancar(False)`, y eso no es verdad, si cambias esa linea por `print(miMotoE.arrancar(False))` observaras que este lo retorna inmediatamente, no lo guarda en memoria, si quieres que lo guarde crea una variable que almacene esa informacio como por ejemplo self.estaArrancando.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Acabo de solucionar el problema gracias a tu consejo

Comment: Genial, publica tu respuesta explicandola. :P

Comment: Pregunta ya editada con la solución. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: No lo hagas en tu pregunta, tu puedes crear una respuesta y marcarla como correcta.

Comment: Esta seccion es de comentarios, crea una respuesta.